# responsive image with background + padding

Tags: html, css

I have a lot of icon images, but I need each icon to have a frame and most importantly, I need them to be responsive

final example of how I need it (Adobe XD)

[image]

**NOTE: the frame should be fixed/unique, only dynamic thing will be the inside icon**

the code i have so far

```css
.special-icon {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 3rem;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url('https://yungsilvadev.s3.amazonaws.com/icon_wrap.svg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="special-icon">
    <img src="https://yungsilvadev.s3.amazonaws.com/hat.svg">
  </div>
```

Comment: add the padding to the container or use margin

Comment: @TemaniAfif does not solve.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **cover** for background image in that way it will auto resize and crop as the device display change

```
background-size: cover;
```

full example:

```css
.frame{
  width:20%;
  height:200px;
  padding: 3rem;
  margin:10px;
  background-size: cover;

}
.row{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.f1{
    background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/103/500/500);
}

.f2{
    background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1003/500/500);
}

.f3{
    background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1011/500/500);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="frame f1"></div>
    <div class="frame f2"></div>
    <div class="frame f3"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: doesn't work :( can you test this with my images? whereas it needs to be responsive, both the image / icon inside and the frame

Answer (score 0):

Works until like ~82px, hope thats enough :D

```css
.special-icon {
  background-image: url('https://yungsilvadev.s3.amazonaws.com/icon_wrap.svg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
}

img {
  width: 35%;
  padding: 20%;
}

.resizable {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px dotted black;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  resize: horizontal;
}

.floaty .special-icon {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="resizable">
  <div class="special-icon"  style="width: 100%;">
    <img src="https://yungsilvadev.s3.amazonaws.com/ruler.svg">
  </div>
</div>
  
<div class="floaty">
  <div class="special-icon" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;">
    <img src="https://yungsilvadev.s3.amazonaws.com/hat.svg">
  </div>
  
  <div class="special-icon" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">
    <img src="https://yungsilvadev.s3.amazonaws.com/ruler.svg">
  </div>

  <div class="special-icon" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
    <img src="https://yungsilvadev.s3.amazonaws.com/hat.svg">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: is cutting when it's big :(

Comment: when placing another icon also destroys everything, try placing that https://yungsilvadev.s3.amazonaws.com/ruler.svg

Comment: @YungSilva tweaked the values a bit, looks as you can get with unknown image proportions.